# InDesign automatically copy text

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I am currently looking for a method to automatically copy text from one position onto another. Let me try to explain this a little bit better:

I have created a quick survey form in InDesign where I have an area for "Customer Name" - what I would like to achieve now is that the customer name that I enter will also automatically be used in the footer, e.g. Proposal made for 'Customer Name'

Is there any simple trick to get this done?

Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you the one who fills in the customer name? Directly in InDesign?

Comment: Hello Random O'Reilly, yes I would be the one creating the documents. I was simply looking for a solution to this in order to save some time as I have the customer name appearing in several areas and I would just be nice to have this step somehow "automatized"

Answer (score 1):

Look at adding a custom text variable.
you would add the variable placeholder in all of the places where you would want it to appear. then you would just have to update the variable and it will update across your document.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS6A9BE096-77B2-4721-9736-797C4912B6C9a.html